# How can we describe this factorization process?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, factoring

We know that, there exist infinite number of algebraic expressions, so that we can not factorise these with real coefficients. For example,

1. $a^2+b^2$
2. $a^2+b^2+c^2$

The simplest example, $a^2+b^2$ can not be factored over $\Bbb R$.

But, I want to consider the factorization like the one below.

$$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a+b-\sqrt {2ab})(a+b+\sqrt{2ab})$$

But, what is the mathematical name of this type of factorisation? Is this a really factoring operation?

**Edit:**

Ah, I see that the, people misunderstood my question, maybe I was not clear.

I know that,

$$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a+b)^2-(\sqrt {2ab})^2=(a+b-\sqrt {2ab})(a+b+\sqrt{2ab})$$

I am aware $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

But, my question is different here.

I wonder how this factoring operation is positioned in mathematics.

I mean, in which mathematical sense, this can be considered as factoring?

$$a^2+b^2=(a+b-\sqrt {2ab})(a+b+\sqrt{2ab})$$

How can we describe/define this factorization process?

$$a^2+b^2=(a+b-\sqrt {2ab})(a+b+\sqrt{2ab})$$ over $?$

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes of course. Because, $(a+b)^2-(\sqrt {2ab})^2$

Comment: @MorganRodgers I assume that "factoring $a^2 + b^2$" ordinarily refers to factorization over the bivariate polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[a, b]$ (up to multiplication by a constant).  OP's examples seem to be working over a ring such as $\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}]$ (?).

Comment: The [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) provides some special cases where the sum of two squares can be factored.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Please see my edit.

Comment: > I wonder how this operation is positioned in mathematics. 

Could you explain what you mean by positioned?

Comment: It is a common situation to have an expression which cannot be factored in a certain mathematical context but can be factored in a wider context. The $a^2+b^2$ is such an example; can't be factored in the context of real polynomials, can be factored in the context of real algebraic functions. Similarly, $5$ can't be factored in the integers (not counting $5=5\times1$) but in the "Gaussian integers" (q.v.) you get $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. So it's still factorization, but with respect to an extended domain.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your comment close 
to my question. People misunderstood me, because of english is my second language

Comment: Your issue is essential in Computer Algebra systems that usually aren't "able" (with quotes) to obtain such generalized factorizations.

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe I need some improvement for the question. People can misunderstood the question's exact meaning

Comment: I thought my comment was exactly your question. You wanted to know whether your formula could be called a factorization. I wrote that it can be, provided you recognize that you have changed the context in which you are permitted to find factors.

Comment: So, what more do you need, 1094359?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for all your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, note that $a^2+b^2 = (a-bi)(a+bi)$ is also a factorization.  Your factorization is a factorization over the ring $\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}]$ and over $\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{ab}]$.  My factorization over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i].$

The polynomial $x^2-3$ factors over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ as
$(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3}).$

Factorization depends on the ring one is factoring over.  So, in that sense, the such factorizations are "positioned" in the context of the ring.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = a +b$ and let $v=\sqrt{2ab}$. Now we have $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)$ so it's just a quadratic in disguise.

Comment: See my edit please. Thank you

Comment: @user1094359 ok I saw it. Are you familiar with completing the square? It's what motivates the $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$ step.

Comment: Ah, yes I understand. But my question is completely different

Comment: @user1094359 I mean at the end of the day it's just a quadradic so there isn't much to say about it. Are you looking for a broader explanation of factoring in an algebraic setting? There is a more general notion of a decomposition which can generalize things like the primes, polynomial factorization and matrix decompositions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if
$a=c^2$ and $b=2d^2$
then
$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a+b-\sqrt {2ab})(a+b+\sqrt{2ab})$
becomes
$c^4+4d^4
=(c^2+2d^2)^2-4c^2d^2
=(c^2+2d^2-2cd)(c^2+2d^2+2cd)
$
which is an
unexpected factorization
with integer coefficients.

Comment: and, if we take $d = \frac{g}{\sqrt 2}, ...$

Comment: But then you have $\sqrt{2}$ in the factors. The purpose was to show how the original $ab$ factoring with $\sqrt{}$ could lead to another factoring without it - only integers.

Comment: huh.  I was regarding the original as a polynomial in variables $a,b,$  maybe the OP does not do that.